# ¿"Carta de comida" o "carta de restaurante"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

En una frase como esta:

> Él tradujo dos archivos de una carta de comida/una carta de restaurante y editó la traducción de uno más

¿Qué opción sería la más adecuada? Lo que pasa es que fueron 3 archivos que incluyeron listas de comida que pertenecen al mismo restaurante: dos necesitaron traducción y el tercero ya estaba traducido, pero necesitaba edición.

Answer (score 6):

Yo siempre he oído usar ***carta*** a secas para referirse a la explicación de los platos de un sitio. No necesita ningún calificativo adicional.

> [**carta**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7jSjnZM)
>   Del lat. charta, y este del gr. χάρτης chártēs.
>   5. f. En un restaurante o establecimiento análogo, lista de platos y bebidas que se pueden elegir.

Sin embargo, la palabra puede resultar ambigua o confusa en este contexto:

> Él tradujo dos archivos de una **carta** y editó la traducción de uno más.

Por lo que se podría añadir *del restaurante* para indicar que esa carta es de restaurante y no una carta de otra cosa, tipo carta epistolar o de baraja:

> Él tradujo dos archivos de una **carta del restaurante** y editó la traducción de uno más.

Comment: Sí, es por esa amigüidad muy posible que yo hice esa pregunta. :D
Muchísimas gracias. De hecho, el restaurante no está mencionado en ningún lado más en el texto. Por eso, creo que debo decir "de restaurante", ¿no?

Comment: @مريممعاذ yo creo mejor _del_ restaurante que _de_, pues te refieres a un restaurante en concreto.

Answer (score 5):

Creo que puedes escoger cualquiera de lo dos. *Carta* está bien y es suficiente. Si quieres un sinónimo, puedes usar

> **[menú](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OxXW1rR)**
>
> Del fr. *menu*.
>
> **2**. m. Carta del día donde se relacionan las comidas, postres y bebidas.

Aunque tiene el mismo problema de *carta*, esto es, puede ser ambiguo y confundirse con el "menú" de los programas informáticos.

> *Él tradujo dos archivos de un menú y editó la traducción de uno más.*

Comment: Sí, por eso yo hice esta pregunta. Muchas gracias. :)

Answer (score 4):

En un restaurante (restorán) yo suelo pedir la *carta* con la intención de ver que ofrece el *menú* ese día. Más exactamente, la carta para mí es una lista de todos los platillos que puede uno pedir, mientras que un menú suele anunciar una secuencia fija que constituye una comida completa (de la sopa al postre). Si has dejado claro previamente que la discusión es acerca de un restaurante, ninguna de las dos palabras necesita clarificación.

Pero un problema secundario es que no se está traduciendo un archivo, sino una carta. Para evitar confusión (y asumiendo que no has mencionado el restaurante antes), yo diría

> Él tradujo una carta de restaurante...

Comment: Bueno. Lo que pasa es que fue la misma carta, no fueron 2, pero había sido dividida entre 3 archivos. Por eso, yo mencioné la palabra archivos. ¿Es tan mala? Debo decir "Él tradujo una carta de restaurante y editó la traducción de una parte de ella"? ... No sé, es bastante confusa la situación. Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¡Ah, ahora se me ocurrió una sugerencia! jaja ¿Es mejor decir "Él tradujo parte de una carta de restaurante y editó la traducción de la otra parte"?

Comment: Otra pregunta (y disculpen la molestia), generalmente, ¿se puede decir que alguien "tradujo 2 cartas de un restaurante"? O sea, ¿un restaurante puede tener más de una carta? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Por lo que veo en tus últimos comentarios a mi respuesta anterior, tu problema es un poco diferente; es un problema de estilo...

A mí me sucede frecuentemente que no puedo escribir una frase satisfactoria: que diga todo lo que necesito decir, en el orden correcto y sin crear confusión. Creo que ese es tu caso, pues tu dominio del español no parece ser el problema. Asi que ¿cuál es la solución?

Simplemente escribe lo que quieres, usando más de una frase:

> Él tradujo dos archivos y editó la traducción de un tercero. Los archivos contenían varios menús del restaurante bla-bla-bla.

Como ves, el quid del asunto es separar los dos fragmentos de información que quieres presentar. Una vez que te das cuenta de esto, puedes volver a presentar todo en una única frase (si así lo requieres). Por ejemplo:

> De tres archivos que contenían menús de un restaurante, él tradujo dos y editó el tercero.

Comment: Buena respuesta, Rodrigo. Tiene algo de _coaching_ y todo :)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la respuesta. Me ha sido de mucha ayuda para formar la frase de una manera que vaya bien con el contexto. Ahora, por favor, confírmame la nueva frase. "Él tradujo dos archivos de un restaurante y editó la traducción de un tercero para una empresa de traducción en España. Los archivos consistieron en cartas del restaurante citado." Muchas gracias.

Comment: Puedes pasarte media hora decidiendo entre "consistieron" y "consistían". Pero básicamente tu última versión es clara y concisa. No sufras más.

Comment: Muchas gracias.